# HAProxy Change Farm and Soft Stop Server on current farm

Tags: haproxy

Im pretty new to load balancing and using HAProxy.
After doing a lot of reading and setting up my own development environment, I am unable to work out the following:
I have a bank of web servers which traffic is being balanced across, how do I soft stop these servers whilst i fail over to a new bank?

My test congif looks like this:

```
frontend front-end-test
  maxconn 2000
  bind 192.168.0.10:8666
  use_backend back-end-test-a

backend back-end-test-a
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server machine1 10.1.1.92:44410 weight 1 maxconn 2000 check
    server machine2 10.1.1.92:44420 weight 1 maxconn 2000 check

backend back-end-test-b
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server machine3 10.1.1.92:44430 weight 1 maxconn 2000 check
    server machine4 10.1.1.92:44440 weight 1 maxconn 2000 check
```

To change banks the config would be updated and the hot restart used:

```
frontend front-end-test
  maxconn 2000
  bind 192.168.0.10:8666
  use_backend back-end-test-a
```

To

```
frontend front-end-test
  maxconn 2000
  bind 192.168.0.10:8666
  use_backend back-end-test-b
```

So to recap, I need to update the config so my backend farm changes but any requests for the original servers still need to be served by them.
Is this possible?

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if I want to change backends, I would switch it right away (as in change to `use_backend back-end-test-b`) and do a graceful reload by delaying SYN packets (new incoming connections) before restarting the haproxy service. Ex:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8666 --syn -j DROP
sleep 1
service haproxy restart
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 8666 --syn -j DROP
```

The delay should allow running requests to finish before that service restarts and applies the new config.

This may not work for long running transactions though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could have long running connections to the web servers whilst synchronous searches are happening. Therefore delaying new incoming connections isnt really possible.

Comment: Though, I did do a couple of tests.    

Config was pointed to server bank A, connection to server was opened, updated the config to bank B and restarted HAProxy. 
Original connection was dropped.   

Config was pointed to server bank A, connection to server was opened, updated the config to bank B and restarted HAProxy using hot reload.  
Original connection was maintained but then new requests were round robined across both banks :S